Bivariate normal conditional expectation calculation
Question:
I have the following setup: Let Z and W be jointly normal random variables constructed as follows:
$ Z = X $, $ W = \rho X + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2} Y $,
where $ X $ and $ Y $ are independent standard normal random variables (i.i.d. $ N(0, 1) $), and $ \rho $ is a correlation coefficient.
I am trying to find $ E(W | Z) $.
My approach:
Since $ W $ is a linear combination of $ X $ and $ Y $, and we are given that $ Z = X $, I used the following steps:
Since $ Z = X $, we know $ E(X|Z) = E(X|X) = X $.
Since $ X $ and $ Y $ are independent, we also have $ E(Y|Z) = E(Y|X) = E(Y) = 0 $.
Thus, the conditional expectation becomes:
$E(W|Z) = \rho E(X|Z) + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}E(Y|X) = \rho X$.
Since $ Z = X $, we have:
= $\rho Z$
My questions:
Is this approach correct?
How would one compute $ E(W | Z) $ using an approach based on integrals? I know this is possible using the joint distribution of $ Z $ and $ W $, but I’m not sure of the exact steps.
Thanks in advance!

It is correct, natural and very simple. Why do want to do it any other way?

A general fact: If $U$ and $V$ are jointly normal, then $E(V|U)=cU$ for some constant $c$. [Also, linear combinations of jointly normal r.v.'s are jointly normal].

I just wanted to get some practice on it doing it the integral way
